# Нужна помощь с разбором механизма решения задачи.(Спираль)

Tags: python

Требуется вывести квадрат, состоящий из N×N клеток, заполненных числами от 1 до N2 по спирали. (Решение снизу). Мне необходимо понять то, что именно обозначают строки, которые закомментированы как "# - что происходит здесь?" - Я запринтовал отдельно каждый цикл и понимаю, какие именно числа выводят циклы и в каком порядке, но не понимаю - почему именно они так делают. Также ни один из циклов не выводит последнее число (например 81 при n==9), хотя код в целом его выводит.

```
#mat - результирующая матрица
#st - текущее значение-счетчик для записи в матрицу
#m - коеффициент, используемый для заполнения верхней
#матрицы последующих витков, т.к. одномерные матрицы
#следующих витков имеют меньше значений
n = int(input())
mat = [[0]*n for i in range(n)]
st, m = 1, 0
# Заранее присваиваю значение центральному элементу
# матрицы
mat[n//2][n//2]=n*n # - это центральная позиция в матрице или наиболее близкая к центру, в конце
for v in range(n//2): # 
    #Заполнение верхней горизонтальной матрицы
    for i in range(n-m):# - что происходит здесь?
        mat[v][i+v] = st # - что происходит здесь?
        st+=1
        #i+=1
    #Заполнение правой вертикальной матрицы
    for i in range(v+1, n-v): # - что происходит здесь?
        mat[i][-v-1] = st # - что происходит здесь?
        st+=1
        #i+=1
    #Заполнение нижней горизонтальной матрицы
    for i in range(v+1, n-v): # - что происходит здесь?
        mat[-v-1][-i-1] =st # - что происходит здесь?
        st+=1
        #i+=1
    #Заполнение левой вертикальной матрицы
    for i in range(v+1, n-(v+1)):# - что происходит здесь?
        mat[-i-1][v]=st # - что происходит здесь?
        st+=1
        #i+=1
    #v+=1
    m+=2
#Вывод результата на экран
for i in mat:
    print(*i)
```

Comment: Если вкратце, то здесь пять циклов: один внешний и четыре вложенных. Внешний цикл - перебирает витки спирали (в матрице 7х7 будет 3 витка). Первый внутренний цикл записывает в верхнюю строку спирали значения счетчика с каждым витком сдвигаясь вправо на одну позицию. Второй - записывает в правую колонку, начало и конец цикла сдвинуты на номер витка, номер текущей колонки - это номер витка со знаком минус (т.е. последний элемент списка) и еще -1 (так как прямая индексация от 0, а обратная от -1). Третья и четвертая аналогично.

Answer (score 0):

Цикл `for i in range(...)` используется для перебора чисел. Если между скобками один параметр - переменная `i` идёт от нуля до параметра-1 (особенность синтаксиса). Если передаётся 2 параметра, то `i` идёт от 1-го параметра до 2-го (опять же -1). Подробнее про этот цикл читайте [тут](https://pythonchik.ru/osnovy/cikl-for-v-python).

Вызывается `mat[x][y] = z` - это значит, что элемент `y` в элементе `x` матрицы будет равен теперь `z`. Покажу на примере:

**Имеется:** `mat=[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`

**Пишем:** `mat[0][0]=777`

**Получаем:** mat=`mat=[[777, 2], [3, 4]]`

Почему пишем `[0][0]`, а не `[1][1]`? Да потому что индексация элементов списка начинается с 0, а не с 1.

На этих двух примерах Вы поймёте все строки, отмеченные `# - что происходит здесь?`

Помог?

Comment: @JackieRorh , [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте и примите ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)